# CSS Styling a specific page

Tags: customization, css, child-theme

I am familiar with styling specific pages on WordPress by adding a class

```
.page-id-123
```

in front of the styled element. However, this doesn't seem to apply to "subpages" (sorry don't know what they are called), when after the page, there is a specific tag (?) added.

Example:

URL: wordpressweb.com/my-account

CSS: `.page-id-123 .header { background-color: yellow; }`

URL: wordpressweb.com/my-account/**?add-new-business=true**

CSS: `??? .header { background-color: yellow; }`

Is there a way to target these kind of pages with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a URL Query String. It's still the same page, not a subpage. You can access this in PHP via `$_GET` and you can use the [`body_class` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) to look for this query string and add a class accordingly. WordPress won't add classes for query strings, it's not a normal thing to do.

Here's an example of how you can use the `body_class` hook to add an additional class based on the query string:

```
/**
 * Look for query string and add an additional class to the body
 *
 * @param Array $classes
 *
 * @return Array $classes
 */
function wpse352069_body_class_mods( $classes ) {

    if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['add-new-business'] ) && true == $_GET['add-new-business'] ) {
        $classes[] = 'add-new-business';
    }

    return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse352069_body_class_mods' );
```

If that query string exists and IS true then it will add the `add-new-business` class to the body tag. You can use the CSS below to style it:

```
body.add-new-business .header { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: I think `$_GET` being a superglobal, it always exists and you don't have to check if it is set. Also wouldn't a strict comparison `'true' === $_GET['..` be better? Or, since it only matters if it is set, a `if (!empty($_GET['add-new-business'])) {` could replace that complete line

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!!! I'm new to php and this was super helpful :)